# Google Analytics in Android App fails to send Screen name

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google Analytics V4 in my Android app, and I have experienced some problems while implementing it.

The Google Analytics seems incapable of sending several Screen Names when transition between them is fast.

```
public void onResume
{
    super.onResume();

    Tracker tracker = getApplicationContext().getTracker();
    // Set screen name.
    tracker.setScreenName(screenName);  
    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());    
}
```

This code is being called on Fragment's onResume function.
All works fine when Fragments are loaded one by one, slowly, I mean, that transition between screens is not very fast, but, when transition between screens is very fast;
which means one fragment is loaded, then this fragment in turn loads a different fragment, then Google Analytics doesn't reflect the last screen information in Real Time, just the first Fragment, but, on LogCat you can see that all fragments were successfully sent with their screen name to GA, but only the first Screen Name is displayed.

Any ideas how to solve this? Why if GA says it sent the screen name, it is not shown on Real Time???